# System.OutOfMemoryException with asp:FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, out-of-memory

I have an ASP.NET page that has a FileUpload control inside.
When I try to upload a third file I am getting:

System.OutOfMemoryException
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()

here's my code:

```
<td style="width: 60%; height: 67px; vertical-align: top">
    <div class="fileinputs" id="div2" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle">
        <div id="div3" class="fakefile" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; vertical-align: middle">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFileUpload" runat="server" Width="265px" CssClass="borde-form"
                Height="15px" ValidationGroup="docs" />
            <img name="imgExaminar" alt="Examinar" src="../../Images/botExaminar.gif" style="cursor: hand;
                width: 81px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle" />
        </div>
        <asp:FileUpload EnableViewState="true" ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Width="368px"
            Height="19px" CssClass="hidden" />
    </div>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvattachment" runat="server" OnServerValidate="cvattachment_ServerValidate"
        ControlToValidate="fileUpload" ErrorMessage="Existe un archivo con el mismo nombre"
        Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small" ValidationGroup="docs"></asp:CustomValidator>
</td>
<td style="width: 30%; height: 67px; vertical-align: top">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAdjuntar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/botAdjuntar.GIF"
        OnClick="imgAdjuntar_Click" ValidationGroup="docs" Height="20px" Width="66px"></asp:ImageButton>
</td>
```

When I click on my imgAdjuntar, I am getting the error, but the imgAdjuntar_Click method is never called, but the Application_Error on the Global.asax is fired instead.
Plus, none of my breakpoints are being stepped into, the error occurs before reaching the application code.

Maybe the control is the one that's failing?
What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help?  [System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception when uploading a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905723/system-outofmemoryexception-exception-when-uploading-a-file)

Comment: I've already seen that, but the thing is that my code is never even reached! the error occurs even before anything is executed in my code.

Comment: I'm specifically thinking of the "maxRequestLength" web.config property mentioned in the question, and the link mentioned in the top-voted answer.  Did you look at those two settings?

Comment: Yes, I changed those parameters but I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are not storing files within the ViewState.

In addition, try to disable the ViewState for the entire page.

Check the following treads, which may be helpful:

[How do i handle 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in uploading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809059/)

[Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown](http://forums.asp.net/t/1701236.aspx)

Comment: That was it! I changed all ViewState storage, for Session storage. Thank you!